# What services are required for AppFabric to run properly and monitor WCF Services

Tags: wcf, iis-7, appfabric

I'm running AppFabric on IIS7 with Windows 7 for development.
AppFabric works fine for some period of time, but then it will stop updating.
I can send service requests through, and AppFabric doesn't show them in the dashboard when I refresh it.

I think a service is stopping, or there's a permission issue. Does anyone know what services are required to for AppFabric to run properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server and AppFabric Event Collection Service, off the top of my head (for event collection; there are other services, but since you say AppFabric itself runs requests, I presume they're OK). There's also Event Tracing for Windows, but it's not, strictly speaking, a service.

I presume you've also checked the tracking profile is set correctly and have looked in the Application event log?

Comment: I restarted the services and it started working again. Weird.